# React App crashes when importing component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using `react-admin` framework (3.2) and I am struggling with following error:

```
ReferenceError: Cannot access 'GameScheduleField' before initialization
```

This is how I import the `GameScheduleField` component to my resource:

```
import { GameScheduleField, GameScheduleInput } from '../components/GameScheduleComponents';
```

I also import atleast eight other components without any issue. The `GameScheduleField` is a class and it looks like this:

```
export class GameScheduleField extends React.Component
{

    constructor(props, context)
    {
        super(props, context);
    };

    static defaultProps =
    {
        addLabel: false,
    }

    rowStyle = (record, index, defaultStyle = {}) =>
    {
        const style = color => ({
            ...defaultStyle,
            borderLeftWidth: 5,
            borderLeftStyle: "solid",
            borderLeftColor: color,
        });

        switch (record.type)
        {
            case "q": return style("yellow");
            case "v": return style("cyan");
            case "adv": return style("magenta");
            case "fin": return style("green");
            default: return style("gray");
        }
    }

    render()
    {
        const { source, record, ...rest } = this.props;
        const seq = get(record, source, []).map((v, i) => ({ order: i + 1, ...v }));

        return <ArrayField record={{ data: seq }} source="data" {...rest}>
            <Datagrid rowClick="expand" rowStyle={this.rowStyle} expand={<GameStepField />} setSort={() => {}}>
                <TextField source="order" label="hf.order" />
                <SelectField source="type" choices={GameStepEnum} />
            </Datagrid>
        </ArrayField>
    }
}
```

Any suggestion why am I getting this error linked to this specific component?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Any code about how you use `GameScheduleField`? Or an online demo?

Comment: Is it any relevant to this issue though? I mean the issue seems to be in imports.

Comment: Not sure after view some of the issues related, guessing you could try to start with adding normal `constructor()` and `super()`

Comment: @keikai also whats weird to me is, this project was running on react-admin version 2.9 just fine, then I updated to 3.2 and these issues just started poping out.

Comment: Didn't see any correlation with `react-admin` from your current code

Comment: @keikai I have added a constructor as well - nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when u have circular dependency. for example. follow below given comment.

- You have a circular dependency issue:

  http/private : import store from "app" components/headerNav: import
  apiPrivate from "http/private"; and then app imports your component
  tree So, because of that, http/private is going to get loaded first
  and try to grab the store from app, except app hasn't actually been
  loaded yet because it's waiting on the component tree to be imported.

Source:

https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-toolkit/issues/167